# Primary Key Error on .Find with single Id Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having an issue with performing a .find on an entity with a single PK.

The base class is as follows;

```
public abstract class Entity : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool? IsArchived { get; set; }
}
```

and the class is

```
public class Manufacturer : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

however, when i attempt a HTTPPUT on the Manufacturer i get the following error;

> The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity.
>   Parameter name: keyValues

This is thrown when I call the .find method on the set;

```
    public T Find<T>(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        return this.Set<T>().Find(id, includes);
    }
```

Any ideas why this is occurring?

**Update**

I am running Code first. The database has generated (this is through VS table design) PK_dbo.Manufacturers (Primary Key, Clustered: Id)

I am operating a SOLID architecture, where my controller is as follows;

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("")]
    public Manufacturer Put(Manufacturer m)
    {
        var response = ManufactureService.UpdateManufacturer(m);

        return response.Result;
    }
```

where the ManufacturerService is as follows;

```
    public ServiceResponse<Manufacturer> UpdateManufacturer(Manufacturer obj)
    {
        Func<Manufacturer> func = delegate
        {
            using (var context = _contextFactory())
            {
                var manufacturer = context.Find<Manufacturer>(obj.Id);
                manufacturer.Name = obj.Name;
                manufacturer.IsArchived = manufacturer.IsArchived;

                context.Update(manufacturer);

                return manufacturer;
            }
        };

        return this.Execute(func);
    }
```

where obj is the passed Manufacturer to be updated. and the id is an integer.

to give a little more info, I have a  contect which then uses the following;

```
    public T Find<T>(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        return this.Set<T>().Find(id, includes);
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like your entity has two (or zero) primary keys keys defined.

Comment: I agree. but what doesn't add up is the fact that I inherit from Entity on a number of of different classes where the put is working??. I have also tried adding the [Key] attribute. An ideas on further investigation I can do?

Comment: Which type of approach are you using? Code first or data first?
If the answer is the first and you have set the PK in your edmx remember to update the database.

Comment: Code first. I'm not using a .edmx though. I thought this may be the issue and ran an add-migration the up method was blank though.

Comment: Why are you putting everything inside a Func?  Are you over-simplifying the code in your application in an effort to make it easier for us to understand?

Comment: How can `this.Set<T>().Find(id, includes)` even compile? The signature is `Find(params object[] keyValues)`.

Answer (score -1):

If its failing on Manufacturer, and the only column is Name, then it makes zero sense that your call stack is blaming Find(int id).  There is no integer primary key on this table. Maybe that is your problem.

UPDATE

Please try copying the code in the Entity class into Manufacturer.  Then remove the subclass relationship.  Then see if your put still fails.

Comment: John, thanks for your comment, it inherits form the Entity base class which has an int Id though.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the Service call to .find

Comment: @JohnZabroski this is mere speculation, not an answer.  This should have been posted as a comment requesting additional clarification about the schema.

Comment: @DavidL appreciate the comment. As edited above the schema seems to point to a single PK in the base class Id.

Comment: @DavidL any ideas on what could be causing this issue? do you require any further code?

Comment: @DavidL I think I have a valid point, and updated my line of thinking to reflect it.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

You pass two key values to Find but EF would only deduce that Id is a PK.  Do you really want a nullable bool as part of your PK?  I'm not sure if this is allowed.  If you do want the nullable bool as part of your key then I think you will need to let EF know about it.

Comment: ok, I see how you have come to this conclusion, but I have tried adding the attribute [Key] to the id with no success (I have done this and ran a migration as proof where the Up() method shows no db changes)

Comment: Your call to Find is passing 2 keys.  You need to have two keys defined.